# Is there a way to see the underlying error when a yum_package command fails?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

So here's something that irks me with Chef, and I'm wondering if there's a way to improve it.

When a resource fails to execute on a node, for example a yum_package resource, we never see the underlying error. All we see is for example:

`[2015-01-21T11:51:18-05:00] ERROR: yum_package[expat-devel] (git::default line 14) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec:  returned 1, expected 0`

This doesn't help me whatsoever in troubleshooting why the yum command failed, so I have to usually go and run the command myself and look at the yum output (oh - the package isn't found, dependency problem, etc, etc...).

Is there a way that Chef can output the stdout/stderr when a command returns a non-zero status so I can see right away why it failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-l debug` to your chef-client or chef-solo command. It will show a lot more output, including the stdout and stderr from all subcommands.